# Is authentication effectively decentralised?

Tags: keymanagement

I can't quite see the solution to this; so I'm questioning for clarity. My understanding from [the docs](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-ethereum/9781491971932/ch04.html) is that it *appears* that the process is dentralised:

1. Generate your private key (according to certain recommendations).
2. Generate your public key from the secp256k1 implementation.
3. Generate your Ethereum address.

Is that how it works? If it is it looks decentralised.

---

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how it works.

Anyone can create the keys, even offline. So in that sense there is no central authority to issue or authorize keys. But otherwise I wouldn't really call it decentralized as it's not much related to (de)centralization. Otherwise I could also call me eating a bread decentralized.

Comment: https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bread?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you expand on what you mean by "decentralization" please as it clearly is a word whose definition we may not match on.

Comment: Well that's a rather complicated topic. You can check for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decentralization#:~:text=Decentralization%20or%20decentralisation%20is%20the,central%2C%20authoritative%20location%20or%20group. or, if you have something more specific in mind regarding Ethereum, feel free to post a new question